# Loading "llama-2" 8 bit quantized version onto the GPU

Tags: pytorch, langchain, large-language-model, llama, llama-cpp-python

Based on this repo [GitHub Link](https://github.com/kennethleungty/Llama-2-Open-Source-LLM-CPU-Inference) I am trying to build a system which answers users queries.

I was able to run the model on a CPU with response time of ~60s, now I want to improve the response time, so I am trying to load the model onto a GPU.

**System specs**

- Processor - Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6238R CPU @ 2.20GHz, 2195 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 2 LogicalProcessor with 24GB RAM
- GPU - Nvidia A40-12Q with 12gb.

So here are my queries

1. How to load the llama 2 or any model onto the GPU?
2. Can we improve the response time if we load the model onto a GPU?
3. How to improve the answer quality?
4. How should we make the model to answer the questions related only to the documents?

**The CODE**

```python
from langchain.llms import CTransformers
from dotenv import find_dotenv, load_dotenv
import box
import yaml
from accelerate import Accelerator
import torch
from torch import cuda
from ctransformers import AutoModelForCausalLM

# Check if GPU is available and set device accordingly
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
print(f"Using Device: {device} in llm.py file")



# Load environment variables from .env file
load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

# Import config vars
with open('config/config.yml', 'r', encoding='utf8') as ymlfile:
    cfg = box.Box(yaml.safe_load(ymlfile))

accelerator = Accelerator()


def build_llm():

    config = {'max_new_tokens': cfg.MAX_NEW_TOKENS,
                            'temperature': cfg.TEMPERATURE,
                             'gpu_layers': 150
                             }
    llm = CTransformers(model=cfg.MODEL_BIN_PATH,
                        model_type=cfg.MODEL_TYPE,
                        config= config
                        )
    llm,config = accelerator.prepare(llm,config)
    return llm
```

This is the part which loads in the model, but while querying, the cpu utilization shoots up till 100% and the GPU utilization remains at 2%

Comment: It doesn't look like you use `device` anywhere or pass it to anything.

Answer (score 0):

1. How to load the llama 2 or any model onto the GPU?

Since you're using `accelerate`, the best way to do this is check the [accelerate docs](https://huggingface.co/docs/accelerate/en/basic_tutorials/migration). Note that standard Llama2 is too large for your GPU, so you may need to use a quantized version.

2. Can we improve the response time if we load the model onto a GPU?

It depends. Most speed gains from GPU inference come from batch inference. If you're running inference on a single item at a time, you might not see major speed improvements. Inference on a single item tends to be more bottlenecked by memory transfers rather than flops, which is why codebases like [llama.cpp](https://github.com/ggerganov/llama.cpp) get good performance on laptops.

3. How to improve the answer quality?

You can try improve the prompt you give the model or curate a dataset of proper question/answer pairs for fine-tuning.

4. How should we make the model to answer the questions related only to the documents?

This is an open research question

Comment: First, thanks for answering my question, I am using Llama-2 7B 8 bit quantized which should fit in a 12GB memory right? Otherwise, suggest me or share some article links how to run a GGUF/GGML/GPTQ models on GPU?

Answer (score 0):

When I got in contact with the people who are working on this, informed me that "ctransformers[cuda]" is used to load the model onto the GPU, but The CUDA version used by ctransformers is 11.7.1 [link](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/error-cuda-driver-version-is-insufficient-for-cuda-runtime-version-using-triton-22-08-image-in-apptainer-container/274478) , but I am using CUDA 11.4.2 which does not support this, that is what is restricting me from loading the model onto the GPU.

Thanks,

Will keep you posted on this issue.